# Is it possible to use pod securitycontext fsGroup on a DockerKubernetes hostpath PersistentVolume?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to run an MS SQL Server instance in DockerKubernetes and the image requires fsGroup: 10001 to be set on the data volume. But fsGroup does not seem to have any effect on the volume and MS SQL Server fails to load with access denied on the data volume mounted in the Kubernetes stateful set. The image starts fine without the PV mounted.

Is there any documentation on docker hostpath storageclass? I could only find examples, but no reference docs.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up your cluster?

Comment: Hello @maloo. Any updates?